# How can I automatically add the Trademark symbol to specific words in Indesign CC while typing?

Tags: adobe-indesign, trademark

I want to add the Trademark symbol after three words in my document. These three words occur a lot in the work I am doing and sometimes I miss instances of these words.

Is there a way I can add a TM after a specific word while typing?

Comment: Find and replace?

Comment: an option, although prefer while typing so I don't have to worry about it being done. Just one less thing on the final checklist. (Have amended the question to reflect this)

Comment: Using what operating system? On the Mac™ you can get the symbol by pressing "option/alt - 2."

Comment: You (or your client) may be making this more complicated than necessary. Using a trademark symbol is entirely optional. Not only does it not need to appear next to every instance of a trademarked symbol or phrase, it doesn't add any legal protection to do so. Adding the symbol the first time the phrase appears in a document is common practice, and it is entirely sufficient to add a disclaimer that the symbol or phrase is a trademark.

Comment: Look here for guidelines:
https://www.inta.org/trademarkbasics/factsheets/pages/trademarksymbolsfactsheet.aspx

Comment: @13ruce, if you forget to add ™ just once people might steal that instance of the word. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I am doing this with m<sup>2</sup> in surface areas. Assuming you're using a Paragraph Style, you can attach a GREP Style to that and each time there's a word of any length ending in 'tm' followed by a space or a comma, a particular Character Style can be applied so that the 'TM' is automatically formatted.

Alternatively, some fonts (you need to check your font) may have a dedicated 'TM' character in their glyphs, and this can also be helpful.

[image]

- GREP query can probably be improved, but this is a basic setup

Comment: This will not add the characters “TM”, which is what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want with the Autocorrect feature.  (well... almost*)

The thing is that adding a glyph into the "correction" field is a bit tricky, but doable. Here's how:

First, go Edit > spelling > enable Autocorrect.

Then, you'll need to locate and modify the Autocorrect XML file.
Most likely, it does not exist already, unless you already have set at least one autocorrect wordpair. If not, to generate this XML file, go Preferences > Autocorrect and type any wordpair (mind the language):

[image]

Now that you have created the XML file, locate it.
I'm using CS6/Win7, so mine will be here: 
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\InDesign\Version\language\Autocorrect\English USA.xml

Now, open the XML, and you can now create custom autocorrection using `&#x2122;` for TradeMark glyph.
(FYI: 2122 is the unicode value for the ™ character)

Save the XML and restart Indesign (important!)
Here you go:

[image]

*** Additional and important note:**
Now that you know that you can change a word while typing, please be aware that autocorrect doesn't always work when the word is followed by some characters (dot, dash, exclamation mark...) Which makes all this kinda useless really ^^
So, my best advice will be to double check by using a Grep F/R:

[image]

Comment: I would have tried that too. You saved me the disappointement of finding out the hard way that it doesn’t work in some frequent cases. Note: I think you’re confusing glyohs and characters; you’re only talking about characters here. When you say “adding a glyph”, it seems you mean “adding some characters”.

Comment: Yeah you're right. Common mistake I admit.
 "Special Characters" they are, not glyphs (but not just "some characters" ^^)

Answer (score 1):

Text Variable will be the simplest and most manageable way to handle this - create a New Text Variable for your product name, insert that once. Then copy it in Story Editor - you can Find & replace as text or GREP, paste that one insert symbol/tag and get it everywhere, AND if later the trademark changes.... it's easy to manage.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't use Text Variable in InDesign! :'o Have to explore that! Also Story Editor (I often work bilingual, English-Arabic and often had to go back and forth texts)! Why didn't I realize that?!